# dynamic zipcode option to a weather plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins

I am trying to use a weather plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/fleeting/a4hbL/light/

which asks for either zipcode or woeid. I don't want to hard wire the zipcode there. I would rather zip code is dynamic so people spread over various locations can use the site, with the plugin working for their location. I am trying to auto detect their location using their IP and a webservice that geolocates based on IP.

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
  var items = [];
  var zip = data["zipcode"]; 

});
```

I need to pass the zip to the plugin below: 
  $.simpleWeather({
    zipcode: 'zip',
    ...
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no below, `$.getJSON` is async, so you do it in the success handler :

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
    $.simpleWeather({ zipcode: data.zipcode });
});
```